How to resolve invalid package error when implementing recaptcha in flutttter?
I'm using the recaptcha_enterprise_flutter package - version 18.4.2.
I want to implement recaptcha functionality in my application. I'm using the example repository on github.
recaptcha-enterprise-flutter
But I'm getting this error:

The error occurs in initClient()
  void initClient() async {
    String siteKey = Platform.isAndroid
        ? widget.config.androidSiteKey
        : widget.config.iosSiteKey;

    var result = false;
    var errorMessage = "failure";

    try {
      result = await RecaptchaEnterprise.initClient(siteKey, timeout: 10000);
    } on PlatformException catch (err) {
      debugPrint('Caught platform exception on init: $err');
      errorMessage = 'Code: ${err.code} Message ${err.message}';
    } catch (err) {
      debugPrint('Caught exception on init: $err');
      errorMessage = err.toString();
    }

    setState(() {
      _clientState = result ? "ok" : errorMessage;
    });
  }

Has anyone faced this problem?

Verify the list of packages imported used on your flutter app:
package com.google.flutter.recaptcha
import android.app.Application
import androidx.annotation.NonNull
import com.google.android.recaptcha.Recaptcha
import com.google.android.recaptcha.RecaptchaAction
import com.google.android.recaptcha.RecaptchaClient
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.plugins.FlutterPlugin
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.plugins.activity.ActivityAware
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.plugins.activity.ActivityPluginBinding
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodCall
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel.MethodCallHandler
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel.Result
import kotlinx.coroutines.GlobalScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

